# MS Word File Name and Time counter in services vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, windows-services

I'm make a service to track when a file open and close. I have got the name of file when it opens and add that name into list. But when I close a word file WMI notify that a file is closed , I'm unable to get the closed file name.

Management event watcher tracker when a word file open or close. `Process.GetProcessByName("winword")` to get the name of opening process

**Management Event Watcher:**

```
 For Each a In str

  startstr += "processname = '" + a + "'" + " OR "
   Next
    startstr = startstr.Substring(0, startstr.Length - 4)
        qrstart = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WITHIN 1 WHERE " + startstr + ""
        qrstop = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WITHIN 1 WHERE " + startstr + ""


            startWatch = New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery(qrstart))

            AddHandler startWatch.EventArrived, _
                AddressOf startWatch_EventArrived
            Try

                startWatch.Start()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Ex {0} ", ex.ToString())
            End Try

            stopWatch = New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery(qrstop))
            AddHandler stopWatch.EventArrived, _
                AddressOf stopWatch_EventArrived
            Try
                stopWatch.Start()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Ex {0} ", ex.ToString())
            End Try


            FileTxt.Close()
Private Sub startWatch_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
        Dim FileTxt As System.IO.StreamWriter
        FileTxt = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("E:\text.txt", True)
        FileTxt.WriteLine("Process started: {0} at Time {1}", e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value, Now)
        'FileTxt.WriteLine("Time of start : {0}", Now)
        FileTxt.WriteLine()
        FileTxt.Close()

    End Sub
```